# How to get uploaded image in serverside using Ember.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm stuck with a problem I need to save the uploaded image in db but I dont know how to do that I wrote code for upload the image but i'm stuck with passing it to the server my current code is given below

App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.PreviewImageView = Ember.View.extend({
        attributeBindings: ['name', 'width', 'height', 'src'],
        tagName: 'img',
        viewName: 'previewImageView',
        printme: function () {
            console.log('in previewImageView');
        }
});
App.FileField= Ember.TextField.extend({
    type: 'file',
    attributeBindings: ['name'],
    change: function (evt) {
        var input = evt.target;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                this.$().parent(':eq(0)').children('img:eq(0)').attr('src', e.target.result);
                var view = that.getPath('parentView.previewImageView');
                view.set('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
                {{view App.FileField name="logo_image" contentBinding="content"}}
                {{view App.PreviewImageView width="200" height="100" }}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can mix some traditional MVC methods to solve your problem. from your current code I can assume that showing a preview of the image is completed so to get that file in server side just use the following code in your html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="file" {{view Wizard.FileField contentBinding="content"}} />
<input type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
}
```

and In you controller method you can access the file like this

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
         // Do what you want
}
```

To save the image in db you have to convert it into bytes (sql server 2008 support image now but db like postgresql still need image as bytes) to do that use the following method

```
 MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
 file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
 byte[] bytes= target.ToArray();
 return View();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using ember-data, you can create a model to represent the image and then create/save from the reader's onload callback. For example:

```
App.LogoImage = DS.Model.extend({
  id: DS.attr('number'),
  attachment: DS.attr('string')
});

//in App.FileField...
reader.onload = function (e) {
  this.$().parent(':eq(0)').children('img:eq(0)').attr('src', e.target.result);
  var view = that.getPath('parentView.previewImageView');
  view.set('src', e.target.result);
  var file = e.srcElement.result;
  var logo = App.LogoImage.createRecord({ attachment: file });
  logo.save();
}
```

Comment: and how can I access it is "HttpPostedFileBase file"enough to get that file in serverside

Comment: I got error on "var file = e.srcElement.result;" the error is  "Unable to get property 'result' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Sorry, i think that should have been e.target.result

Comment: I got an error on var logo = App.LogoImage.createRecord({ attachment: file }); "Error: Unable to get property 'createRecord' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: sounds like `App.LogoImage` is not defined.

Comment: how to get that uploaded image in serverside